# Getting the middle name from a full name field

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I've got functions to get the first and last names, like so:

```
create function udf_get_first_name (@string nvarchar(100))
    returns nvarchar(50)
as
begin
    declare @first_name nvarchar(50)
        set @string = ltrim(@string)
        set @string = rtrim(@string)

    if dbo.udf_get_number_of_spaces(@string) > 0
        set @first_name = left(@string, charindex(' ',@string) -1)
    else
        set @first_name = @string
    return @first_name
end

create function udf_get_last_name (@string nvarchar(100))
returns nvarchar(50)
as
    begin 
        set @string = ltrim(@string)
        set @string = rtrim(@string)
        if dbo.udf_get_number_of_spaces (@string) > 0
            begin
                set @string = reverse(@string)
                set @string = left(@string, charindex(' ', @string) -1)
                set @string = reverse(@string)
            end
        return @string
    end
```

I need to be able to get the middle name, and just can't wrap my head around what I've been reading through my searching so far. Not sure if I'm just being dumb or not.

I also need to be able to sort a name formatted as L/M/F, into the proper columns as well, which I'm having an even harder time with.

Edit: Not all the records have middle names.

Comment: Do *all* of your records have a middle name? Because middle names are not a common feature for humans. (Also you have discovered a design flaw in your database. Don't make tables that require a function call for sorting properly.)

Comment: Oh good point. They don't all have them, but several do. I'll edit the OP to say that.

Comment: The function calls are part of what I'm learning at this point, so I can't really not use them XD

Edit: It's all stuff on data warehousing, so we're just taking a bunch of data from various places and have to sort it all with the functions. Does strike me as kinda messy, but does seem to make some sense so far.

Comment: Do people have double middle names? Or double last names? Are they hyphenated or otherwise delimited? What do you consider a middle name?

Comment: Nope. Those that do are just a single middle name or initial.

Comment: which sql server version your are using?

Comment: Version 15.0.18040.0

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to [Sebastian Brosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3840840)'s answer. I also added the TRIM function after I saw his answer. In this query, it's not necessary. But it's something nice to have. For example, if the user added multiple spaces by mistake, this will remove that.

There might be a better or simpler way to get first, middle and last name. But this is the way I come up with at the moment.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitFullName(
    @FullName NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Format NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @FN NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @MN NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @LN NVARCHAR(MAX); 
    DECLARE @RV NVARCHAR(MAX); 

    SET @FN = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@FullName,0, CHARINDEX(' ',@FullName))));
    SET @MN = RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@FullName, CHARINDEX(' ',@FullName) + 1 , LEN(@FullName) - (CHARINDEX(' ',@FullName) + CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@FullName)))+1)));
    SET @LN = RTRIM(LTRIM(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@FullName),0, CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@FullName))))));

    IF (@Format='FN') 
        SET @RV = CASE WHEN LEN(@FN) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE @FN END;
    ELSE IF (@Format='MN') 
        SET @RV = CASE WHEN LEN(@MN) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE @MN END;
    ELSE IF (@Format='LN') 
        SET @RV = CASE WHEN LEN(@LN) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE @LN END;;
    ELSE
        SET @RV = CONCAT(@LN, ' ',  CASE WHEN LEN(@MN) = 0 THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(@MN , ' ') END, @FN);

    RETURN @RV;
END;
```

Example 01

```
SELECT dbo.SplitFullName('Antonio P. Green', 'FN')  AS FN,
       dbo.SplitFullName('Antonio P. Green', 'MN')  AS MN,
       dbo.SplitFullName('Antonio P. Green', 'LN')  AS LN, 
       dbo.SplitFullName('Antonio P. Green', 'LMF') AS LMF;

+---------+----+-------+------------------+
|   FN    | MN |  LN   |       LMF        |
+---------+----+-------+------------------+
| Antonio | P. | Green | Green P. Antonio |
+---------+----+-------+------------------+
```

Example 02

```
select dbo.SplitFullName('Cindy Bertha Collier Sproles', 'FN')  AS FN,
       dbo.SplitFullName('Cindy Bertha Collier Sproles', 'MN')  AS MN,
       dbo.SplitFullName('Cindy Bertha Collier Sproles', 'LN')  AS LN,
       dbo.SplitFullName('Cindy Bertha Collier Sproles', 'LMF') AS LMF;

+-------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+
|  FN   |       MN       |   LN    |             LMF              |
+-------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+
| Cindy | Bertha Collier | Sproles | Sproles Bertha Collier Cindy |
+-------+----------------+---------+------------------------------+
```

Example 03

```
SELECT dbo.SplitFullName('Tristan Jackson', 'FN')  AS FN,
       dbo.SplitFullName('Tristan Jackson', 'MN')  AS MN,
       dbo.SplitFullName('Tristan Jackson', 'LN')  AS LN, 
       dbo.SplitFullName('Tristan Jackson', 'LMF') AS LMF;

+---------+------+---------+-----------------+
|   FN    |  MN  |   LN    |       LMF       |
+---------+------+---------+-----------------+
| Tristan | NULL | Jackson | Jackson Tristan |
+---------+------+---------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution, using a function to get a part of the name or the fullname in a specified format:

```
--
-- function to get a part of a fullname or to reformat the fullname.
-- @fullname - the fullname to get the part from or to reformat.
-- @format - the format of the output using F (firstname), M (middlename) and L (lastname).
-- the function returns the fullname in specified format or NULL if input is not valid 
-- or the part of name is empty.
--
CREATE FUNCTION GetNamePart(@fullname VARCHAR(200), @format VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN

  -- replace multiple spaces of the fullname and trim the result.
  SET @fullname = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@fullname, ' ', '<>'), '><', ''), '<>', ' ')))

  -- get the different name parts (firstname, middlename and lastname) of the fullname.
  DECLARE @first_name VARCHAR(100)
  SET @first_name = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', @fullname))))
  DECLARE @last_name VARCHAR(100)
  SET @last_name = LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(@fullname)))))
  DECLARE @middle_name VARCHAR(100)
  SET @middle_name = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@fullname, LEN(@first_name) + 1, LEN(@fullname) - LEN(@first_name) - LEN(@last_name))))

  -- init the formatted name of the fullname.
  DECLARE @formatted_name VARCHAR(100)

  -- return only the formatted name if format string is valid.
  IF PATINDEX('%[^LMF]%', UPPER(@format)) > 0
    SET @formatted_name = ''
  ELSE
    BEGIN
      SET @format = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@format, 'M', '##M##'), 'L', '##L##'), 'F', '##F##')
      SET @formatted_name = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(UPPER(@format), '##F##', @first_name + ' '), '##M##', @middle_name + ' '), '##L##', @last_name + ' ')))
    END

   -- check the input (@fullname) for valid value (firstname, lastname or firstname, middlename, lastname).
   IF PATINDEX('%_ %_% _%', @fullname) = 0 AND PATINDEX('%_ _%', @fullname) = 0
     SET @formatted_name = ''

   -- return the new formatted name and replace multiple spaces.
  RETURN NULLIF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@formatted_name, ' ', '<>'), '><', ''), '<>', ' '), '')
END
```

This function `GetNamePart` is using two parameters (`@fullname` and `@format`). The first parameter `@fullname` is the fullname containing the firstname, lastname and if available the middlename. The second parameter is defining the output format of the name. You can use the letters `F` (firstname), `M` (middlename) and `L` (lastname) to define the format of the output.

So you can use the function `GetNamePart` to get the middlename of the fullname:

```
SELECT dbo.GetNamePart(fullname, 'M') FROM table_name
```

... or to reformat the fullname like this:

```
SELECT dbo.GetNamePart(fullname, 'LMF') FROM table_name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=744861ea3d96371dae8d3743cfcea0bd) *(demo and test cases)*

---

But you can also use a `SELECT` query to get the various parts of the name without a function:

```
SELECT
  LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)))) AS first_name,
  LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(fullname))))) AS last_name,
  LTRIM(RTRIM(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%_ %_% _%', fullname) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname) + 1, (CHARINDEX(' ', fullname, CHARINDEX(' ', fullname)+1)-(CHARINDEX(' ', fullname) + 1))) ELSE '' END)) AS middle_name
FROM table_name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b389f4b8ebfc76a2e6dc34985418ecb)

Comment: Cool cheers! I'll try that as well in the morning and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Given it a shot, and have one problem so far. If I just select the full name, I get "Mary J. Smith", but the middle name comes out as "J. Sm". It happens with most of the names I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using Multiple comma separated CTE.

```
declare @str nvarchar(max) ='kareena kapoor khan';

with 
t0 AS (select charindex(' ',@str) pos, @str name ),
t1 AS (select charindex(' ',@str,pos+1)pos,@str name from  t0)
select substring(t0.name,0,t0.pos) "firstName",
       substring(t0.name,t0.pos+1,(t1.pos-t0.pos)) "MiddleName",
       substring(t0.name,t1.pos+1,(len(t0.name)- t1.pos)) "Lastname" 
from    t0
inner join t1 on t0. name= t1.name
```

**output**

|firstName |    MiddleName  |Lastname

|kareena   |    kapoor      |khan

Also, Instead of creating 3 function for first name , middle name and last name you can just create a single function and pass parameter as @namepart.

Comment: Using a single function makes sense, having 3 separate ones has been part of the work so far. I'll give that a shot in the morning though thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The future is start as sql-server 2016:
use STRING_SPLIT function

```
Use Northwind
Go

SELECT ProductID, value  
FROM Products  
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ProductName, ' ');
```

by this query you can split names... then use by Row() function you can choose middle name.

---

STRING_SPLIT requires the compatibility level to be at least 130. When the level is less than 130, SQL Server is unable to find the STRING_SPLIT function.

Comment: one solution is here by function... very better than this way

Answer (score -1):

Select Ltrim(SUBSTRING(name,CharIndex(' ',name),
   CAse When (CHARINDEX(' ',name,CHARINDEX(' ',name)+1)-CHARINDEX(' ',name))<=0 then 0 
   else CHARINDEX(' ',name,CHARINDEX(' ',name)+1)-CHARINDEX(' ',name) end )) as MiddleName
    From TableName